# How to write an java application that takes a sql query and a number as input and fire it

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc

How to write an java application that takes a sql query and a number as input and fire it those many times as number establishing a database connection using jndi lookup.

Comment: The SQL query will be a select query.

Comment: JNDI? Why would you do that? Why not just execute a statement?

Comment: @Srefan : Wrong question meaning?

Comment: @Daniel: Ok fine , then tell me how can I just execute that statement.

Comment: @Shahid: Did you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends very much on the DB you are using. But here is an example [for Oracle](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC). In general, you will need a `Connection`, a `Statement` and a `ResultSet`

Answer (score 0):

This the answer/piece of code I was looking for:

public void runUserQuery(final String userString, final int userInput)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
        System.out.println("Executing " + userString + " "+ userInput );
        class NewDao extends JdbcDaoSupport {

```
        public NewDao() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
            JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
            bean.setJndiName("<JNDI Name>");
            bean.afterPropertiesSet();
            DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) bean.getObject();
            setDataSource(dataSource);


        }

        public void executeQueryMultiple() {
            int index = userInput;
            while (index > 0) {
                this.getJdbcTemplate().execute(userString);
                index--;
            }
        }

    }
    ;
    NewDao dao = new NewDao();

    dao.executeQueryMultiple();

}
```

Unfortunately I could not make you guys understand and got negative vote. :D